# How to build NortelCpl AMP vxworks AMP code?

Tags: c, batch-file, vxworks

How to build NortelCpl AMP vxworks AMP code?

vxworks version is 5.5
OS is Vxworks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an avanexShell.bat file click on that.
then follow the below series of command

```
C:\AMP_2088_fullcode>rem A command shell with Avanex build variables.
WARNING: AVANEX_BUILD_LABEL was NOT set. Use may use one of the following variants...
set AVANEX_BUILD_LABEL=AMPL000000APPL000000002066
set AVANEX_BUILD_LABEL=AMPL000000APPL000000002088
set AVANEX_BUILD_LABEL=AMPL000000APPL000000002089
set AVANEX_BUILD_LABEL=OPDH000001APPL000000000128
set AVANEX_BUILD_LABEL=OPDH000001APPL000000000134
set AVANEX_BUILD_LABEL=OPDH000001APPL000000000142
AVANEX_BUILD_ROOT=C:\AMP_2088_fullcode\
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\AMP_2088_fullcode>set AVANEX_BUILD_LABEL=AMPL000000APPL000000002088

C:\AMP_2088_fullcode>buildamp.bat > 20130120_1511_build.log 2>&1
C:\AMP_2088_fullcode\Release\nortelCPL_AMP\AMPL000000APPL000000002088>
```